# Reusing src/dest location for multiple grunt concat operations

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I currently have this setup using [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat):

```
concat: {
    injectedJs: {
        'dist/js/inject/beatportInject.js': ['src/js/thirdParty/jquery.js', 'src/js/inject/beatportInject.js'],
        'dist/js/inject/streamusInject.js': ['src/js/thirdParty/jquery.js', 'src/js/thirdParty/lodash.js', 'src/js/inject/streamusInject.js'],
        'dist/js/inject/streamusShareInject.js': ['src/js/thirdParty/jquery.js', 'src/js/thirdParty/lodash.js', 'src/js/inject/streamusShareInject.js'],
        'dist/js/inject/youTubeInject.js': ['src/js/thirdParty/jquery.js', 'src/js/thirdParty/lodash.js', 'src/js/inject/youTubeInject.js'],
        'dist/js/inject/youTubeIFrameInject.js': ['src/js/thirdParty/jquery.js', 'src/js/thirdParty/lodash.js', 'src/js/inject/youTubeIFrameInject.js']
    }
}
```

This code works, but there's obviously a lot of non-DRY code in these strings.

I'm hoping to clean this up by express the fact that I:

- Always want 'dest' to be 'dist/js/inject/'
- Always want 'src' to begin with 'src/js/'

So, in my mind, I could say something similiar to this pseudo-code:

```
concat: {
    injectedJs: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            dest: 'dist/js/inject/',
            cwd: 'src/js'

            //'beatportInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'inject/beatportInject.js'],
            //'streamusInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/streamusInject.js'],
            //'streamusShareInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/streamusShareInject.js'],
            //'youTubeInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/youTubeInject.js'],
            //'youTubeIFrameInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/youTubeIFrameInject.js']
        }]
    }
}
```

My thoughts fall short at that point. Is this possible to achieve with Grunt, or do I need to have a fair bit of repetition?

Comment: If you're willing to use commonjs and webpack, you would only need to declare the entry points. As far as I know, you won't be able to achieve something much better with `concat` simply because the destination file names are different.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the config is just plain javascript, so the easiest solution that doesn't involve hacking Grunt is simply

```
function prefix(fileConfig) {
    var newFileConfig = {};
    var distPrefix = 'dist/js/inject/';
    var srcPrefix = 'src/js/';

    for(var dest in fileConfig) {
        newFileConfig[distPrefix + dest] = srcPrefix + fileConfig[dest];
    }

    return newFileConfig;
}

grunt.initConfig({
    concat : {
        injectedJs : {
            files: [
                prefix({
                'beatportInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'inject/beatportInject.js'],
                'streamusInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/streamusInject.js'],
                'streamusShareInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/streamusShareInject.js'],
                'youTubeInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/youTubeInject.js'],
                'youTubeIFrameInject.js': ['thirdParty/jquery.js', 'thirdParty/lodash.js', 'inject/youTubeIFrameInject.js']
            })
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

As to your actual problem, concatenating scripts, it seems that what you really should look into is something like Browserify or WebPack. That will save you a whole lot of trouble.